# Как сделать заглавной первую букву в строке?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, строки

Такой вариант не работает:

```
let name = 'john';

name[0] = name[0].toUpperCase();

console.log(name[0]);

console.log(name[0].toUpperCase());
```

Подскажите пожалуйста вторая строка кода разве не должна изменить и переписать регистр первого знака в строке?

Comment: В ES6 по указателю в строке можно только читать, удалить или перезаписать нельзя.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185/are-javascript-strings-immutable-do-i-need-a-string-builder-in-javascript

Comment: @renich, не только в ES6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поэтапно:

```js
const name = "john"

// делим слово на отдельные буквы
const splitted = name.split("")

// делаем первую букву в массиве заглавной 
const first = splitted[0].toUpperCase()

// копируем массив что бы 
// не модицицировать splitted напрямую
// если вдрг он нам понадобиться далее
const rest = [...splitted] 

// удаляем первую букву из массива
rest.splice(0, 1)

// соединияем все обратно в строку
const result = [first, ...rest].join("")

console.log(result)
// John
```

За раз:

```js
const name = "john"

const result = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)

console.log(result)
// John
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Comment: зачем делать `splice` и затем еще раз копировать, если можно вставить сразу в `splice`? Зачем вообще использовать `splice`, если в массивах **можно** заменять элементы  простым присваиванием?

Answer (score 3):

Так же можно добавить функцию для перевода первого символа в верхний регистр глобально для типа `String`

```js
String.prototype.firstLetterToUppercase = function() {
    return this[0].toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}

const name = 'john';

console.log(
    name.firstLetterToUppercase()
);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо.
Очень полезно, для общего развития!

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант. Принципиальное отличие в том, что меняем именно первую букву, а не любой первый символ в строке. Ведь первым символом может быть и пробел, и дефис, если это диалог, и открывающиеся кавычки при цитировании и т.д.

```js
let str = ' - hi there!';

str = str.replace(/^[^a-zа-яё]*([a-zа-яё])/i, function(m){
    return m.toUpperCase();
});

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = 'john';
name = name.replace(name[0], name[0].toUpperCase()); /// 'John'
```

Короткий вариант:
заменяем в строке первую букву `name[0]`, на неё же заглавную `name[0].toUpperCase()`.
Если строка начинается не обязательно буквой (пробел, намбер) то можно и нужно применить regexp, как в одном из уже предложенных вариантов.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

let abc = hello;
abc[0].toUpperCase()+abc.slice(1)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]